# Hibernate criteria.list() sets the session dirty

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have the following queries with the criteria API:

1.

```
ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria<Country>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Code", "%C%"));
IList<Country> countryList = criteria.List<Country>();
```

2.

```
ICriteria criteria = _session.CreateCriteria<Facility>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Like("Visible", true));
IList<Facility> facilityList = criteria.List<Facility>();
```

After the 2nd query, my session gets dirty, while after the 1st query it doesn't. My `Country` entity has only simple properties, the `Facility` has many-to-one and one-to-many as well.

Could you tell me why the session gets dirty?

Comment: What do you understand by "session gets dirty"?

Comment: _session.IsDirty() returns true

Comment: Are you doing something else in the same transaction?  Queries by themselves, AFAIK, don't set the session to dirty.  That happens when you modify an object in a managed session, and Hibernate flags that object as needing to be persisted to the DB, either at the end of the TX, or on a `flush()` call, whichever happens first.  Post more code.

Comment: I realized that the constructor of an entity initialize a field with 0, but the value in the DB is null. When this entity is loaded the field is updated immediately, therefore the session gets dirty.  Anyway setting hibernate loglevel to trace helped me to find the problem.

Comment: From https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=986804, saying "executing query may result in flushing session -> so all dirty objects will be persist/update to db"

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your 2nd query returns one `Facility` object `f1`, and its [EntityKey](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/engine/EntityKey.html) is `k1`. The reason it gets dirty is: Before 2nd query, the same `Session` already held a `Facility` object `f2`, and its [EntityKey](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/engine/EntityKey.html) is same with `k1`! While there is some attributes different between `f1` and `f2`. During 2nd query, executing query make Session do a dirty check, thus Session is considered as "dirty".

How to debug this? You can output all objects current Session holds ***before*** 2nd query (something like `Set<EntityKey> set = session.getStatistics().getEntityKeys();`, refer [Hibernate session.contains( Class clazz, Serializable id )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473828/hibernate-session-contains-class-clazz-serializable-id), @TheReincarnator's answer), I think you should find at least one `Facility`. Then you can debug whether the `Facility` is same with that one 2nd query get (it should be different!).